# SDK Tools like xsd.exe in visualstudioonline

Tags: azure-pipelines, xsd.exe

Is there a way to use SDK Tools like xsd.exe in a Visual Studio Online build?

I have a pre-build task which creates a classes from an XML Schema. On my machine xsd.exe is in my path but not on the build server so it fails.

The generated file is in the repository so I changed the task to only generate the classes if xsd.exe is available (and show a warning otherwise) which solves the problem.

Still like to know if there is a supported way to run the tool. Have tried to look around for environment variables like `SDKToolsPath` but didn't find anything I can use.

Answer (score 1):

The xsd.exe tool is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin` path on Hosted agent, so you can call xsd.exe through Command Line task with full path.

You also can add that path to environment, then you can call xsd.exe directly:

1. Add PowerShell task (Type: Inline Script)

Code:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${env:PATH};C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin";
```

2. Add other tasks to call xsd.exe

Comment: Thanks. Is this really a supported way or will it suddenly break after an sdk update on the agent?

Comment: @adrianm It is the default path of windows SDK, I don't think updating SDK will remove the related tool in that path.

Comment: Om my machine I got `xsd.exe` in SDK 7.0A, 8.0A, 8.1A, 10.0A. Is 7.0A unique in some way.

Comment: @adrianm Not sure, but you can add a [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/variable-groups) for XSD.exe path, then just update the path in variable group directly.